# Indexing MySQL data with ElasticSearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, full-text-search, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I would like to get some feedback from anyone who's had experience indexing MySQL data with ElasticSearch for full-text searching.  How did you accomplish this?  I've been researching this a bit and unfortunately I've noticed that ElasticSearch has no official plugin to accomplish this although I've come across three different 3rd party tools:

- elasticsearch-river-jdbc
- go-mysql-elasticsearch
- elasticsearch-river-mysql

I'm unsure which one would be best in terms of performance although I suspect the Go tool might have an advantage due to it's compiled nature and the fact that it uses the mysql binary logs.  I would appreciate any advice or examples anyone could provide me with.

Thanks!

Comment: River is deprecated.. not available after ES version 2.0 .. so don't use it
I came across one another plugin ElasticSearch-JDBC .. https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc which can help you but for JDBC you will require ElasticSearch and ElasticSearch-JDBC of same version otherwise it wont work

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
you can now use Logstash to do it..here is an useful blog about it [click ere](https://qbox.io/blog/migrating-mysql-data-into-elasticsearch-using-logstash)

well you can use mysql UDF functions in mysql triggers to execute external scripts, which will index the newly updated or inserted data in elasticsearch. thats one way. [check this](https://rshahriar.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/how-to-run-udfexternal-shell-script-in-mysql-5-5/) to see how to's on mysql UDF